# Affété, maniéré, affecté, guindé

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, grec

En essayant de traduire en français l'adjectif grec *επιτηδευμένος-epitidevménos* (*affected* et *stilted* sont deux mots anglais approchant son sens), j'ai rencontré plusieurs adjectifs :

> Affété, maniéré, affecté, guindé

Quelles sont les différences entre eux ?

Pourquoi *affété* est-t-il désuet ?

Comment: Il faut la préposition « en » devant « essayant » ; la forme verbale en « en » est un gérondif, qui modifie le verbe « rencontré » ; dans la langue littéraire « en » est parfois omis utiliser « en » est préférable : https://www.espacefrancais.com/le-participe-present-ladjectif-verbal-et-le-gerondif/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je dirais qu'**affété** est plus que désuet. Il a disparu du radar...

Pourquoi ? Probablement sa proximité, son double emploi avec **affecté**.

On peut dire des trois autres adjectifs que :

- **Guindé** insiste sur la raideur de l'attitude
- **Maniéré** sur la gestuelle excessive
- **Affecté** sur le manque de sincérité (dans le contexte de la question, le sens n'est pas du tout le même dans *affecté par...*)

Comment: +1 Tous les dictionnaires donne *affété* comme vieilli ( ou « peu usité » : TLF ;-)). Par ailleurs il faut signaler  que le terme est péjoratif (plusieurs dictionnaires) et aussi  « peut devenir synon. de efféminé. ». Manière d'être clairs pour les non natifs. re ;-)

Comment: [remarques de Vaugelas](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qIRycVDLs4AC&pg=PA414&lpg=PA414&dq=aff%C3%A9t%C3%A9+affect%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=634UHaT3NI&sig=ACfU3U1Apb72NEabXdv7tWZKQRjOfb-Hfw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9r76QwvfjAhUk8uAKHS7mDfc4ChDoATACegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=aff%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20affect%C3%A9&f=false). (Pour sourire)

Comment: Merci. @Laure Pour sourire II https://books.google.fr/books?id=c8I-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA316&lpg=PA316&dq=aff%C3%A9t%C3%A9+vs+affect%C3%A9&source=bl&ots=KErhHwU9s5&sig=ACfU3U3HSffgIol1LM63yOPw2wchhoAYgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjn3dzMoPjjAhUHXxoKHeObCHYQ6AEwBHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score -3):

Il y a une différence substantielle entre « affété » et « affecté », de plus que le premier est très peu utilisé (peu us.) ; « [être affété](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aff%C3%A9t%C3%A9) » c'est  être plein [d'afféterie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aff%C3%A9terie), cela signifiant que l'on est sujet à un type d'affectation particulier, en d'autres mots que l'on est affecté d'une façon particulière, et cette façon c'est d'être sujet aux impulsions d'indulger dans un comportement affecté avec l'idée plus ou moins consciente (il me semble que cela peu même venir du subconscient) de plaire à son entourage. Donc être affété c'est avoir un comportement affecté dans lequel transparait en plus un désir de plaire.
« [Être affecté¹](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affect%C3%A9) » signifie «  Qui manifeste de l'affectation, qui manque de simplicité naturelle et parfois de sincérité. »

« [guindé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guind%C3%A9) » (**II A 1**)  a une signification qui est proche de celle de « affecté » mais décrit un comportement caractérisé par une raideur inhabituelle ou une solennité jugée excessive ; c'est un mot que l'on n'emploie pas tellement pour le comportement des gens en général mais pour celui d'une sorte de personnes dans les classes moyennes de la société et au-dessus.  Le sens par extension (**2**) est spécifique à l'allure d'une personne qui semble mal à l'aise en raison de son habillement, ou pour d'autres raisons et il est alors question non pas de raideur mais de gaucherie.

« [Maniéré](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mani%C3%A9r%C3%A9) » peu signifier « affecté », « recherché » ou « exagérément raffiné ». Cependant, lorsque les deux dernières possibilité sont celles qui conviennent, on ne doit plus assumer que le comportement est un comportement copié et/ou pas sincère; le comportement est naturel et il est jugé hors normes par certaines personnes ; c'est une notion assez relative, de même que celle d'être guindé.

Pourquoi « affété » n'est plus utilisé de nos jours ? C'est une question qui va demander beaucoup de recherche si rien n'a encore  été entrepris pour y répondre. Possiblement, l'idée que l'on incrimine les personnes données à un comportement affété d'être motivés par le désir d'entrer dans les bonnes grâces des gens qu'elles côtoient est le responsable, le mot aura été jugé trop moralisateur, mais cela est un peu de la spéculation à tout va.

Comment: "être sujet aux impulsions d'indulger", "les personnes données à un comportement", "les deux dernières possibilité", "une sorte de personnes dans les classes moyennes de la société et au-dessus ".  Sans juger du fond, simple renvoi à un dictionnaire en ligne, au lieu de l'habituel copier-coller, assorti de réflexions personnelles obscures et difficiles à comprendre, la forme est cette fois-ci vraiment trop bâclée pour ne pas mériter un vote négatif.  Faites un effort, LPH.

Comment: @petitrien Je ne vous comprend pas, parlez clairement.